# upload an image and save it in a pdf document with spring boot and angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, image, pdf, itext

I'm a beginner in fullstack Spring-Boot and Angular development, I'm developing an application that requires uploading an image and saving it in a pdf file that is generated with itext 7.
I await your suggestions.

`Service

```
public void export(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
      
    PdfWriter pdfWriter=new PdfWriter(path);
    PdfDocument pdfDocument=new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
    pdfDocument.addNewPage();
    Document document=new Document(pdfDocument);
    String imagePath = "C:\\Users\\21658\\Desktop\\pdf\\logo.jpg";
    ImageData imageData=ImageDataFactory.create(imagePath);
    Image image=new Image(imageData);
    image.setFixedPosition(pdfDocument.getDefaultPageSize().getWidth()/2-320,
                           pdfDocument.getDefaultPageSize().getHeight()/2-160);
    image.setOpacity(0.3f);
    document.add(image);
    document.close();
    
    
}
```

`
Contoller

```
 @GetMapping("/pdf/generate")
    @CrossOrigin("*") 
    public void generatePDF(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd:hh:mm:ss");
        String currentDateTime = dateFormatter.format(new Date());

        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = "attachment; filename=pdf_" + currentDateTime + ".pdf";
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

        this.pdfService.export(response);
        

    }
    
    @CrossOrigin("*") 
    @PostMapping(path="/uploadPhoto")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> uploadFiles(@RequestParam("files")List<MultipartFile> multipartFiles) throws IOException {
        List<String> filenames = new ArrayList<>();
        for(MultipartFile file : multipartFiles) {
            String filename = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/e Commerce/images/"+filenames+".jpg"),
                    file.getBytes());
            //Path fileStorage = get(DIRECTORY, filename).toAbsolutePath().normalize();
            //copy(file.getInputStream(), fileStorage, REPLACE_EXISTING);
            filenames.add(filename);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(filenames);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.